# Exercicio - Recebendo tempo em segundos e retornando a media e os valores menores a media

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um exercicio onde o mesmo solicita que seja criado um programa que receba como entrada tempo de corridas e calcule a media aritmetica dos tempos gastos para percorrer um percurso de corrida diario. Ao final o programa deve exibit todos os tempos que ficaram abaixo da media na mesma ordem que foi recebido na entrada.

ENTRADA:
Diversos valores inteiros, um por linha que represeta os tempos gastos em cada corrida (em segundos), a entrada e finalizada com a inserção de um valor negativo que não devera ser contabilizado.

SAIDA
Na primeira linha devera ser impresso a palavra "MEDIA: " seguido do valor real com duas casas decimais que indica a media dos tempos recebidos. Nas linhas seguintes os tempos que ficaram abaixo da media sendo impressos um por linha.

EXEMPLOS

[image: EXEMPLO]

O que eu consegui ate agora foi o seguinte:

```
lista = []
segundos = int(input())

while segundos >= 0:
        lista.append(segundos)
        segundos = int(input())

media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
print(f'MEDIA: {media:.2f}')
```

Porem nao consegui realizar a impressao dos valores menores que a media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa percorrer a lista fazendo um `if`. Se for menor que a média printa, senão não.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
lista = []
segundos = int(input())

while segundos >= 0:
        lista.append(segundos)
        segundos = int(input())

media = sum(lista) / len(lista)
print(f'MEDIA: {media:.2f}')
for x in lista:
    if x < media:
       print(x)
```

Comment: Evilmaax, deu certo, estava confundindo achando que precisava colocar dentro do White.

Comment: Opa, que bom @MardoquelGadi. Então dá o upvote e marca a resposta como aceita clicando no "Check". Assim você me ajuda, ajuda a si próprio (ganha pontos) e ajuda quem mais chegar aqui precisando dessa resposta. Abraços